# How to get current time in thingsboard MQTT exchange

Tags: thingsboard

request time from thingsboard.io through its time plugin RPC using MQTT. 

**will it be accurate.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getTime():
requestId = '1'
request = {
    "method": "getTime",
    "params": {}
}
client.publish('v1/devices/me/rpc/request/' + requestId, json.dumps(request))
```

and subsrcibe to rpc on connect callback.